# Complete Lorentz metric on (compact) manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry

Let $M$ be  a smooth manifold that is either compact with $\chi(M)=0$ or that is non-compact. Then we can equip $M$ with a Lorentzian metric $g$.

> Can we always equip $M$ with a *complete* Lorentzian metric ?

For a Riemannian metric this is always possible. For instance one can embed $M$ as a closed submanifold of $\mathbf R^n$ and pull-back the Euclidean metric. One can also start with any Riemannian metric $g_0$ and create a complete Riemannian metric $g=e^fg_0$ by making $e^f$ "big" near the Cauchy boundary of $(M,g_0)$, so that curves can't escape from every compact in finite time.

However these two arguments fail in the Lorentzian (or pseudo-Riemannian) case. Does anyone have a reference for such results in Lorentz geometry, even only in the compact case ?

Comment: Regarding compact manifolds, you can always endow $M$ with a Riemannian metric $g$ and use the existence of a nowhere vanishing vector field $X$ (because $\chi(M) = 0$) to define a Lorentzian metric $h(U, V) = g(U, V) - \lambda \langle X, U\rangle \langle X, V\rangle> for $\lambda$ large enough.

Comment: @Romain Gicquaud: the issue is that such a metric need not be complete, since there is no Lorentzian analog of Hopf-Rinow.

Comment: @Nicolas Tholozan: Right, for Riemannian compact manifolds, the equation for geodesics can be rephrased as a first order ODE on the unit tangent bundle which is compact. This is no longer true for Lorentzian metrics. I found this paper on the internet that seems interesting : http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/publ/124/publn124p121-125.pdf This means that if the manifold admits a free $\mathbb{S}^1$-action then you can construct invariant Lorentzian metrics (first construct an invariant Riemannian metric then use the Killing vector field to transform it into a Lorentzian metric)